# How can I convert 1 column dataframe to 3 based on position in python

Tags: python, pandas

I need to convert 1 column into 3 ones using python. my data is of type dataframe

```
My data is:

0 1321.1321
1 text1
2 321113
0 1426.2156
1 text2
2 145454
```

and I want to receive it in the following format:

```
col1         col2   col3 
1321.1321    text1  321113
1426.2156    text2  145454
```

I tried using pivot, reshape but non of them gives my the solution I need

```
My data is:

0 1321.1321
1 text1
2 321113
0 1426.2156
1 text2
2 145454
```

and I want to receive it in the following format:

```
col1         col2   col3 
1321.1321    text1  321113
1426.2156    text2  145454


col1         col2   col3 
1321.1321    
             text1  
                    321113
1426.2156    
             text2  
                    145454
```

Comment: Try `pd.DataFrame(df.to_numpy().reshape(-1, 3), columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])`

Answer (score 5):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for groups by counter by index values with [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) for reshape:

```
g = df.groupby(level=0).cumcount()
df = df.set_index(g, append=True)['col'].unstack(0).add_prefix('col')
print (df)
        col0   col1    col2
0  1321.1321  text1  321113
1  1426.2156  text2  145454
```

If values are reguraly repeated use @Chris A solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.to_numpy().reshape(-1, 3), columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
print (df)
        col1   col2    col3
0  1321.1321  text1  321113
1  1426.2156  text2  145454
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom function to separate the rows like below,

```
def get_type(row):
    type_ = type(row[col1])
    if type_ == str:
        row['type'] = 'grp1'
    elif type_ == int:
        row['type'] = 'grp2'
    else:
        row['type'] = 'grp3'

df = df.apply(get_type, axis=1)
for grp in df.type.unique():
    df[grp] = df[df.type == grp]
df.drop([col1, 'type'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```